# Recommended Hibernate configuration for using a local and a Heroku postgres database

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, maven, heroku

I am developing a `Jersey` application which is connected to a `PostgreSQL` database. I am looking for a solution how to configure `Hibernate` in a way that it always connects correctly to either the local or the `Heroku` based database (depending on if I deploy my application locally or if I push it to `Heroku`).

Using the `Heroku` guides, I tried something like this:

HibernateUtil.java:

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url",
                System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));

        URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));

        String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
        String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':'
                + dbUri.getPort() + dbUri.getPath();
        configuration
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username);
        configuration
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", dbUrl);
        System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation Configuration loaded");

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation serviceRegistry created");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
                .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        return sessionFactory;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 4.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection properties - Driver, URL, user, password -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/MYAPP</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured! -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Mapping with model class containing annotations -->
        <mapping class="com.example.object" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The idea is that HibernateUtil overrides the hibernate.cfg.xml properties (url, user, password). Deploying locally works but deploying to Heroku fails:

remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal de.juplo:hibernate4-maven-plugin:
.1.0:export (default) on project myapp: Execution default of goal de.juplo:hib
rnate4-maven-plugin:1.1.0:export failed: Error calling Driver#connect: Connecti
n to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and t
at the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. Connection refused -> [Help
]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like on Heroku, your app is using the configuration from `hibernate.cfg.xml` instead of the `buildSessionFactory()` method. Can you confirm that the `buildSessionFactory()` is being called?

I think you should remove the `hibernate.connection.*` properties from your `hibernate.cfg.xml` and use `DATABASE_URL` locally. You can either set it in your env, or put it in a `.env` file and run your app locally with `foreman start`, which will pick this file up. This is the best way to ensure pairity between dev and prod environments, and it will test your `buildSessionFactory()` code.

You can even use the Heroku database locally if you desire by [following this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#remote-connections). Capture the Heroku `DATABASE_URL` and put it in your `.env` file. Then add the `ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` args to the JDBC URL.

Comment: It looks like buildSessionFactory() is only called when calling a resource method for the first time (a method which calls the current SessionFactory to get the current Session). I thought this method will be called instantly when pushing to heroku and then It would override the properties according to Heroku's DATABASE_URL. I already set DATABASE_URL locally and this works fine. Is there a way to call buildSessionFactory() when pushing to heroku?

Comment: Okay, I managed to deploy my app on Heroku when using a configuration similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045070/how-do-i-configure-hibernate-orm-on-heroku . But now the problem is that tables are not created automatically when pushing to heroku but I don't know why. I guess because the hibernate.connection information is missing in hibernate.cfg.xml